# If f is a real function, continuous at a and f(a) < M, then there is an open interval I contianing a such that f(x) < M for all x in I.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Can someone please help?

If f is a real function which is continuous at a ∈ R and if f(a) < M for some M ∈ R, prove that there is an open interval I containing a such that f(x) < M for all x ∈ I.

attempt : suppose f is a real function which is continuous in a. Let I be an open interval which contains a point a and f: I → R. Then f is continuous at a ∈ I if an only if f(x) → f(a) as x → a. Then if f(M) - f(a) > 0, then I must be centered say at x_0 such that M - f(x) > 0. Thus f(x) < M for all x in I.

Please can anyone please verify this? And any feedback/hint would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It seems OK, but might be downgraded for not being $\epsilon$-$\delta$ enough. A more conventional proof would start with something like let $\epsilon=\frac{M-f(a)}{2}$.

Comment: And prove |f(x) - f(a)| < (M - f(a))/2?

Comment: Yes, there is a $\delta$ such that if $|x-a|\lt \delta$, then $|f(x)-f(a)|\lt \epsilon$, which forces $f(x)\lt \frac{f(a)+M}{2}\lt \frac{M+M}{2}=M$.

Comment: So, |f(x) - f(a)| = f(x) - f(a) < (M - f(a))/2. Now add f(a) both sides and we get f(x) < (M - f(a))/2 + f(a) = ( M + f(a))/2 < (M + M)/2 = M. Is this how you got to your conclusion?

Comment: Yes, that's it. Let me repeat that your argument is fine, indeed in my opinion better, because it exhibits the geometric intuition. However, at this stage they may want an explicit $\epsilon$-$\delta$ argument.

Comment: I actually like yours too. And it's nice to know another way. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> **Recall that  $f(x)$ is continuous at $a$ if for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists $\delta$ such that for any $|x-a|<\delta$, $|f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon$ holds, i.e., there exists an open interval $I=(a-\delta, a+\delta)$, such that for any $x\in I$, $|f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon$ holds.**

Now let $\epsilon = \frac{M-f(a)}{2}$, clearly $\epsilon >0$, and hence there exists an open interval $I=(a-\delta, a+\delta)$, such that for any $x\in I$, $|f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon= \frac{M-f(a)}{2}$ holds.

Notice that $|f(x)|-|f(a)|\le |f(x)-f(a)|$, hence we have $|f(x)|-|f(a)| <\epsilon= \frac{M-f(a)}{2}$, and hence $|f(x)|<\frac{M-f(a)}{2}+f(a)=\frac{M+f(a)}{2}\le \frac{M+M}{2}=M.$