# If $f$ is a real function, continuous at $a$ and $f(a) < M$, then there is an open interval $I$ containing a such that $f(x) < M$ for all $x \in I$.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity

I have problem regarding the [If f is a real function, continuous at a and f(a) < M, then there is an open interval I contianing a such that f(x) < M for all x in I.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/981971/855456) answer. If I used $\epsilon =M-f(a)$ which is also $\epsilon >0$ and $ \exists$  $  \delta>0$ so there is  an open interval $I$ containing such that $f(x)<M$ for all $x \in I$. I think this is also correct but not sure.

Can anyone verify my answer?

$\underline{Edit}$

Now let $\epsilon = {M-f(a)}$, clearly $\epsilon >0$, and hence there exists an open interval $I=(a-\delta, a+\delta)$, such that for any $x\in I$, $|f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon= {M-f(a)}$ holds.

It follows that $f(x)<M$ for all $x \in I$

Comment: Please write out your entire proof. You expect people to switch between two pages, and to guess what exactly your proof is supposed to be. Simply spell out your own proof and leave out the reference to the other page.

Comment: $\epsilon$ is arbitrary.

Comment: Yes, it is correct, $f(x)<f(a)+\epsilon=M$ for all $x\in I$.

Comment: @RobertZ Is it not good enough?

Comment: It's fine, you are correct.

Comment: @RobertZ Thank you

Comment: This is actually a good question. It reflects the type of math thinking from intuition to proof.

Answer (score 1):

The condition that $f$ is continuous at $a$ indicates that
\begin{equation}
\lim_{x \to a} f\left(x\right) = f\left(a\right).
\end{equation}
In other words, we have the following proposition:
\begin{equation}
\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0, \forall x, 0 < \lvert x-a\rvert < \delta \longrightarrow \lvert f\left(x\right)-f\left(a\right)\rvert < \epsilon.
\end{equation}
And we have the proposition that
\begin{equation}
f\left(a\right) < M.
\end{equation}
Using the fact that $M - f\left(a\right) > 0$, we have
\begin{equation}
\exists \delta > 0, \forall x, 0 < \lvert x-a\rvert < \delta \longrightarrow \lvert f\left(x\right)-f\left(a\right)\rvert < M - f\left(a\right),
\end{equation}
which further indicates that
\begin{equation}
\exists \delta > 0, \forall x, 0 < \lvert x-a\rvert < \delta \longrightarrow f\left(x\right) < M.
\label{main}
\end{equation}
If there is no such open interval $I$ that $f\left(x\right) < M$ for all $x \in I$, then we have the following proposition:
\begin{equation}
\forall \delta > 0, \exists x, 0 < \lvert x-a \rvert < \delta \wedge f\left(x\right) \geq M,
\label{sub}
\end{equation}
which obviously contradicts our conclusion.

Comment: got it thank you